# Creating a custom users resource with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for user registrations and would like to construct a 'show user' page corresponding to the show action in the users controller. Without Devise, one would simply add the line 'resources :users' in routes.rb. But since I don't want duplicate signin, signup etc pages, I cannot use resources :users, and the show user page must be constructed manually. How is this done?

In the users controller, I imagine a simple action like this is necessary:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

The view can also contain something simple:

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

But it is the routes file that I do not understand. Something like:

```
match '/user', :to => 'users#show'
```

doesn't work as you get the error 'Couldn't find User without an ID'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `devise_for :users` and `resources :users` in the same app with no problems at all - mainly for being able to admin users via a backend - you could always limit the resource to just the show method if that's all you need

```
resources :users, :only => ["show"]
```